# sqlite unique index on columns has duplicate data

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a `sqlite` table schema:

```
function createTableEvents(){
  runQuery(`
    CREATE TABLE events(
      devId INTEGER,
      rideId BIGINT,
      ts BIGINT,
      lat DOUBLE,
      lng DOUBLE,
      alt FLOAT,
      spd FLOAT,
      brg FLOAT,
      hepe FLOAT,
      vepe FLOAT,
      ang FLOAT,
      temp FLOAT,
      motion BOOLEAN,
      ignition BOOLEAN,
      mainPower BOOLEAN,
      relayState BOOLEAN
    );
    CREATE INDEX event_id ON cell(rideId, ts), UNIQUE(rideId, ts);`,
    function(result){
      console.log('createTableEvents rows', result.rows.length);
    }
  );
}
```

I have specified `UNIQUE` index for `rideId` and `ts` still I am getting more than one count for a given combination of `rideId` and `ts`.

Comment: Are you sure that a single `runQuery()` call can execute multiple statements?

Comment: runQuery() only exciting one statement. Moved index creation in call back function of create table' runQuery and its working as expected

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for what you want to do is:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_event_id ON cell(rideId, ts)
```

You should be checking the error return status of your code.

Given the nature of your code, I'm guessing you want the index on the `events` table:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_events_rideid_ts ON events(rideId, ts);
```

Comment: Ohh..Thanx for pointing out that. But it happens that runQuery execute only single statement